# Sending a list from Maple to Python

Tags: python, pickle, maple

I am creating a dataset in Maple (using functions that only Maple has) and training an AI using that dataset on Python.

To share information between Maple and Python I use Maple to write a text file in which the information of the dataset is encoded in a list that Python can read. E.g. `dataset_as_list = [[122,523,[1,0,0,2],633,32,"yes"], [342,63,[1,0,3,0],836,41,"no"], ...]`. And later I simply use Python to read the text from that file and to execute it.

However, I was hoping to find a better way of doing this, because the size of the dataset can be huge and `exec()` has a maximum length for the executed string. Something like `pickle.dump()` but in Maple would be ideal.

Thank you in advance,

Tereso.

Comment: Slightly out of scope, however are you *sure* you cannot keep it within Python and just use PyTorch?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the set directly to Python using the [Maple Python Package](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=Python). You will then be able to manipulate it in memory (fast) rather than writing to disk just to read it back in (slow).

Comment: Disclaimer - I have never used Maple but this seems like a sensible solution